# USB flash drives: How to fix?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have recently purchased some so called 256gb Kingston drives that are fake

I used a program called check flash and few other to check for dead sectors and read speed and read and write speed

the results are as follows:

they were reading at 1.35 mbps at best 
they read and wrote at 0.95 mbps
and had a hell of a lot of dead sectors

so what I ask is:

1. Is there a way to drop the size to improve speed
2. Is there any other way to improve speed
3. How can I stop the device from addressing the dead sectors

Comment: 256Gb? if it sounds too good to be true, it probably is.

Comment: yes i found that out lol

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, some people I work with got burned with similar ones. Bin them, they'll never work.

Comment: yes i thought as much they are in process of going back but i have to wait a short period before i cand send them so i got time was wondering if i could drop size to even 4 gb for a reasonable speed

Comment: If they are going back I'd leave them alone. Anyway, would you trust your data on them?

Comment: I don't think the speed problems relate to the stated size. I'd just feel lucky that you found out they were fakes before you were wedged without any recourse...

Comment: These drives CAN in many cases be "repaired" (so that they will report their actual capacity, and will be useful for non-critical storage). I'd still want to verify the integrity of any files copied from this media, but I do that anyway. `md5sum` is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, fake flash drives can be reprogrammed to report their real sizes. This is unlikely to significantly improve speed, but will prevent the drive from writing to bad or nonexistent sectors. [This site](http://fixfakeflash.wordpress.com/) has more helpful articles and informational resources.